# Relation between a basis and the number of vectors for polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to determine if the vectors below form a basis for vector space of polynomials of order 3. The determinant of the matrice below is non zero and it shows that all of them are linearly independent but l read that for a n dimensional vector space, the number of vectors that form a basis should also be n. In this case, l have 4 vectors for a 3 dimensional space, so does that mean that they cannot form a basis ? I am not quite sure on assigning dimensions to polynomials.

$$ ( 2-x^2 , x^3-x, 2-3x^2 , 3-x^3 ) $$

Comment: "polynomials of order 3." Do you mean degree 3? If so, what is the dimension of the  vector space of polynomials of degree 0? Why do you have a square matrix in degree 3?

Comment: @A.G Yes, l meant the degree. So will the dimension be 4 for polynomials of degree 3 ?  In that case, the square matrix makes sense. Am l correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: A standard basis for $R_4[x]$ is $B = (x^3,x^2,x,1)$ which has $4$ independent vectors. So as you said, the dimension is $4$, and accordingly, the basis has 4 independent vectors. Hope it helps